# How to call two consecutive rest api in typescript?

Tags: typescript, rest, rxjs

I am new to typescript. I am facing the below mentioned problem. My scenario is, I have to call two consecutive REST APIs. If get success message from first one, then only I will call the second API. If both are successful, I will return success message, or required to return error message.

My two rest response structure are same. That is :-

```
{
  "timestamp" : "0654848"
  "status" : 200,
  "error" : "Error/Success" 
  "message" : "Failure/Success",    
  "path" : "api/v1/..", 
  "data" : "{}"
}
```

Call is initiating in the below mentioned way in **account-form.component.ts** file.

```
verifyAccount(){

    this.service.validate(this.accountModel).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.status = 200) {
        this._router.navigate(['/home/accountPanel']);
        this.toastr.success(resp.message);
      }
      else{
        this.toastr.error(resp.message);
      }
    },
        );
  }
```

**Service.ts** file :-

```
validate(account: Account): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/api/account/validate`, JSON.stringify(user))
            .pipe(
                **---Help Required in this portion---**
                catchError(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    return response;
                }));
}
```

Other URL is **/api/account/balance**, which is a get call.
I expect : -

**1>** If response from 1st api gets error -> **Return error message of first**

**2>** If response from 1st is correct, but from second gets some error -> **Return error message of second**

**3>** If response from both are success -> **Return success message of the second**

Comment: You can use [`concatMap()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap) or [`switchMap()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) pipeable operators.

Comment: I am trying to find out, how to use it to resolve my issue. If you have any link of example for **concatMap()** for rest call, please provide.

Comment: This article may help: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/ This covers examples for `switchMap`, `mergeMap` and `concatMap`

Answer (score 0):

I have resolver the scenario in the below mentioned way.

```
verifyAccount(){
    this.service.validate(this.accountModel).subscribe((res : any) => {

      if (res.status == 200) {

        this.service.getBalance(res).subscribe((resp : any) => {

          
          if (resp.status == 200) {

          }
          else{
            this.toastr.error(resp.error);
          }
        });
      }
      else{
        this.toastr.error(res.error);
      }
    },
        );

  }
```